# Filtering Objects by a date range

Tags: c#

I'm, currently, trying to make an algorithm that compares an object's capture date (they are images) to a chosen date range from the user. 
The capture date of the image is currently stored as mm/yyyy.

I'm converting to integers the year and month of the capture after they have been split up and stored startMonth and startYear are the users inputted values.

I am converting to integers the year and month of the capture date, after they were split and stored as `month` and `year`.`startMonth` and `startYear` store the values entered by the users.

If it is within the the date range, then I add it to the "DisplayList" from the list that is stored.

I need it to recognise that the beginning month can be greater than the ending month's date. I'm probably missing something easy.

```
string month = split[0];
string year = split[1];

if (startYear <= Convert.ToInt32(year) && endYear >= Convert.ToInt32(year))
{
  if (startYear == Convert.ToInt32(year) && endYear == Convert.ToInt32(year))
  {
    if (startMonth <= Convert.ToInt32(month) && endMonth >= Convert.ToInt32(month))
    {
      DisplayList.Add(ImageList[i]);     // Adds it to the DisplayList                          
    }
  }
  else if (startYear == Convert.ToInt32(year) || endYear == Convert.ToInt32(year))
  {
   if (startMonth <= Convert.ToInt32(month) && endMonth >= Convert.ToInt32(month))
   {
     DisplayList.Add(ImageList[i]);
   }
   else if (startYear == Convert.ToInt32(year) && startMonth <= Convert.ToInt32(month))
   {
     DisplayList.Add(ImageList[i]);
   }
   else if (endYear == Convert.ToInt32(year) && startMonth >= Convert.ToInt32(month))
   {
     DisplayList.Add(ImageList[i]);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create two `DateTime` objects with `month` and `year` and compare those dates? ([`new DateTime(year, month, 1);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: Why not just use one integer? "yyyymm" , so for example Dec 2018 => 201812 then you can simply use "<" and ">" ... (or DateTime of course)

Comment: Are you comparing the dates without days? If yes, then I see only a couple of conditions to get this to work.

Comment: You've made this complex by storing the dates in that pattern. You should simply have used datetime, then query it simply.

Comment: Storing dates as dates allows much easier comparison than all that Convert code

Comment: You might want some validation to check that month and year are actually numbers

Comment: If you stored it as yyyy-mm you could even do a lexical order comparison, I think. But that wouldn't be my favorite neither. Just a thought - and it would not need any conversion whatsoever.

Comment: @Haytam Yes im comparing dates without the days

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah i have validation just left it out mate

Comment: ... a fiddle for the lexical idea: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MFbV3r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having stored your dates as dates would have been simpler, but if you do not have the choice, the following should make it:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(startYear), Convert.ToInt32(startMonth), 1);
var endDate = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(endYear), Convert.ToInt32(endMonth), 1);
var date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(year), Convert.ToInt32(month), 1);

// do whatever comparisons with date, startDate and endDate
if(startDate <= date && date <= endDate)
{

}
```

Also note that having many `if`s to do `DisplayList.Add(ImageList[i]);` is quite odd.
I would try to factor it: *when exactly do I need to add an image to that display list?*

And then use one `if`:

```
if(thatCondition ||
   thisCondition ||
   thatOtherCondition)
{
    DisplayList.Add(ImageList[i]);
}
```

Comment: @DanScott I find my solution clearer, just trying to tell if yours is correct (trying to find edge cases or anything that would break it) is getting me headache. Anyway, my point wasn't about comparison but about conversion to compare in an easier way. For how long have you been on this page before commenting? I edited this answer like 1 hour ago ^^